# How to enable the Views UI module?

Tags: views

I have the Views UI module on my Drupal site, and I would like to enable if but I can't.

How can I enable the Views UI module?

When I try to enable this module by using admin panel I am not able to enable because that

check-box itself disabled and I am not able to check that check-box

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you have the required modules installed and enabled.
Your most probalby missing [Chaos Tools](https://drupal.org/project/ctools)

[Module filter](https://drupal.org/project/module_filter) is also a easier way to manage modules

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Chapabu's answer, if you have access to the drush command line. use

```
drush en views_ui -y
```

Comment: I dont have any commandline option.I am not able to enable it via admin panel

Comment: If you cannot enable it via the module list page, Check if you have the required module ctools installed first. This is the only reason why I think the checkbox would be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Try this by using drush command line:

> drush en -y views_ui

Answer (score 0):

Go to *admin/modules*, scroll down to the Views section (it'll be near the bottom as the list is ordered alphabetically), click the checkbox next to Views UI and then click *Save Configuration*.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all the dependencies of View Module are enabled. After that 'Clear Cache' and then retry. I hope it will work now.